# String Replacement in a sentence has a certain word

Tags: r, stringr

I want to write function is used for trimming the common words

```
trim_common_name <- function (x) {
  v_replacements <- c(
    `[:punct:]` = ""
    # `data.*` = "dataset"
  )
  x %>%
    str_to_lower() %>%
    str_replace_all(., v_replacements) %>%
    str_replace_all(., "_+", "_") %>%
    str_trim()

}
```

In the context, I want to find the word 'data' and replace it with the word 'dataset' regardless the position of 'data' in the sentence. How can I do it?

For example:

'abc data' ---> 'dataset'

'data abc' ---> 'dataset'

'abc data&data' ---> 'dataset'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a regex pattern [as you can see here](https://regex101.com/r/YyJr32/1)

The pattern is `\bdata\b`. A word boundary just specifies that the word starts or ends there, so you don't get incorrect matches like `datatype` ---> `datasettype`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, is this what you were looking for?

```
x <- c('abc data','data abc' ,'abc data&data')
x
[1] "abc data"      "data abc"      "abc data&data"
x[grep("data",x)]<-"dataset"
x
[1] "dataset" "dataset" "dataset"
```

Check on `?grep`